# How can I convert a text file into a form that MPI_Bcast can send?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'am beginner in MPI and C, and I try to improve my abilities but I have a problems and could not resolve them yet.

I have a text file, containing my name in it. The thing that I need to do is that process 0 in MPI should read this text file and send it to other processes. The way that I follow is like the following:

```
if (myid == 0) {    
    // Read myname.txt file and convert it to a string
    char name[100];
    ifstream input("myname.txt");
    for (int i = 1; i < nprocs; i++){
        input >> name;
        cout << name;   
    }
    input.close();

    // Send name and alphabet strings to all processors by means of broadcasting
    MPI_Bcast(&name, 100, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

When I do this, the operations on other processes that utilize this "name" buffer cannot be completed and give such an error:

```
'name' was not declared in this scope.
```

I thing I have a mistake in generating this "&name" address. Could you please help me to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You  have to declare name for all the processes and perform the broadcast from all the processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a place to store your array on all ranks, and `name` is already a pointer:

```
char name[100];
if (myid == 0) {    
    // Read myname.txt file and convert it to a string
    ifstream input("myname.txt");
    for (int i = 1; i < nprocs; i++){
        input >> name;
        cout << name;
    }
    input.close();
}
// Send name and alphabet strings to all processors by means of broadcasting
MPI_Bcast(name, 100, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The call to `MPI_Bcast` is the same on all ranks, no need to put it inside the `if`. The only thing to do on rank 0 is to read the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: I have tried it and the problem was fixed. Thank you!